# Headlights come on by themselves

Tags: headlight, saab

Why would the headlights on a 2006 Saab 9-3 come on by themselves while the car is off and parked?

Comment: original headlights?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a problem with the computer that controls them (which might be the BCM - Body Control Module, or might be a separate dedicated module).

A friend of mine had the same problem with a 2001 BMW, and water had got into said module through a perished seal and shorted a number of connections within it, causing the lights to go on and off at seemingly random times...

Comment: Moisture ingress could definitely be contributing to this problem.